# dynamic div rendering in jquery. cursor moves to start on reload of div

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser

HI I have the jquery script which calls the server every 5 seconds and reload the content (via synchronous ajax call) into div which has a scroll bar enables if the content of the div overflows. now on other browsers when the content of the div is reloaded. the scroll bar maintains its position. but on firefox the scroll bar moves back to the start of div. Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, one option is to store the `scrollTop` of the div prior to reloading the content, and then set it again. E.g.:

```
var scrollTop = $(".foo").scrollTop();

// load some content into .foo, then

$(".foo").scrollTop(scrollTop);
```

Comment: there is just one little thing.. when I reload the content I empty the div and then render the content again . so there is effect of like refresh. Can I remove this effect somehow  ?

Comment: @FaizanAli - I'm really not sure. That would need some experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

try `ajaxSuccess()`;

```
var st;

$('#div').ajaxStart(function(){
   st = $(this).scrollTop();
})

$('#div').ajaxSuccess(function(){
   $(this).scrollTop(st);
})
```